# TSLint and VSCode not showing red-line in .ts file

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, tslint

I have a single `.ts` file where i am learning to configure tslint and tsconfig. I have induced extra spaces and removed semi-colon intentionally to check if tslint is configured properly.

**Using command `tslint filename.ts` i could see tslint could find errors in .ts file but VSCode is not showing those `red lines`?**

I have generated tslint.json and tsconfig.json using CLI: `tslint --init,tsc --init`

[image: no-red-line]

But in angular-app it shows

[image: red-line]

What am i missing? I went to through tslint and tsconfig docs, couldn't find how to configure.

**how to get red-line in normal ts-files?**
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you installed [the required extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint) ?

Comment: [yes](https://i.imgur.com/FDYXou1.png) else in angular app it should not be showing red-line, on adding extra spaces.

Comment: I don't have access to images ...

Comment: sorry i did not get you? did u mean, u cannot see the image i have uploaded in the question above?

Comment: I don't have access to imgur because of my corporate proxy, so I can only see your question and not your screenshots :/

Comment: i have that extension in VSCode. and in angular apps it shows red-line. when i create a plain .ts file in a directory and include tslint, tsconfig, that line is not showing. i have to rely on `tslint <filename>` to see errors and remove them. If i find any way to see those line, removing them would become easier.

Answer (score 2):

Finally found the solution. 
Its basically TSLint extension issue not TSLint CLI itself.
The extension **`need`** `tslint` and `typescript` in node_modules for it to work. 
So i added **package.json**

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "^3.2.1",
    "tslint": "5.11.0"
  }
}
```

and ran `npm install`. Restarted VSCode. I got those red-lines back. :-)

Comment: This worked. Thank you, I was pulling my hair out at this moment. Also be sure to refresh VSCode page or quit and restart it!